# Should I use the EventAggregator or implement INotifyPropertyChanged on my Domain Models when notifying ViewModels of changes in the model?

Tags: wpf, prism, inotifypropertychanged, eventaggregator

I am building a WPF project and have implemented Prism.
I have a DAL where I have a library that handles the connection to the DataBase called Persistence, this library uses `EntityFramework` and has some Entities.
Furthermore I have some DomainModels, now - what do I do with the given scenario:

I have 2 ViewModels that both have a reference of the `ActiveUser` (the one that is currently logged in) as an `IUser` type DomainModel, that we get via a service called `IUserService`.

Lets say that this `IUser` has a property called `Funds`, if `ViewModel1` changes `IUser` - how do i Notify `ViewModel2` that it there are changes to `IUser` and `Funds` should be updated so the `View` is displaying the correct data.

1. Do i Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my Models as well as my ViewModels, and then each `ViewModel` should then listen to the `PropertyChanged` event, and depending on the property that has changed, update accordingly? (I find this kind of ugly though)
2. Do I use the `EventAggregator` and publish/subscribe the events, publishing from my DomainModels(?) and subscribing on my ViewModels?
3. Do I implement something like a `PropertyObserver<TPropertySource> : IWeakEventListener` class?

Thanks

Comment: Is Iuser instance singleton?

Comment: @SatyajitMohanty No it's not

Answer (score 2):

**1.** and **2.** should both do the job, I'd go for **2.** if there are few events like this, otherwise **1.** because it keeps everything on a more local scale.

And btw, if you go for **1.**, go for **3.** also. The `PropertyObserver` makes handling `INotifyPropertyChanged` a lot simpler, because you do not have to consider the lifetime of involved objects (not to speak of the nicer syntax).